# Analytical "density" of a non-inversible (deterministic) function

Tags: real-analysis

So the title might be confusing to some. Let me make this clearer:

**Formally**

Let $f\ :\ x\in(a,b)\ \mapsto\ f(x)$ be a non-inversible function with real scalar values on a finite interval. Let $I_f = f\big((a,b)\big)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be the image of this interval by $f$.

Is there an analytical function $g\ :\ I_f\ \mapsto\ [0,1)$ such that:

- $\int_{I_f}g(x)\ dx = 1$
- $\forall x\in I_f$, $g(x)$ is proportional to "the size of $\{t\ /\ f(t)=x\}$"?

I would appreciate help:

1. Finding a clean formulation of this last property if you understand what I mean;
2. Answering the actual question;
3. Discussing how to extend this "density" definition to the case where $f$ takes multi-dimensional inputs, on possibly infinite intervals, *eg*. $f\ :\ \mathbb{R}^n\ \mapsto\ \mathbb{R}$.

---

**Hand-wavy Example**

Define $f(x) = e^{ -\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 }$ for $x\in(a,b)$.

[image: Plot of $f$ for $\big( \mu=6, \sigma=1, a=2, b=10 \big)$]

I have *no idea* if this is leads to a correct answer to my question, but intuitively, if the derivative of $f$ is large in absolute value, then it is going to spend "less time" at this point, so the density should be lower where the derivative is large in magnitude.

Following this idea, if I define $g(x) = 1 - \frac{|f^\prime(x)|}{\max_t |f^\prime(t)|}$ and I plot $g(x)$ against $f(x)$, I obtain something that looks like a density to me:

[image: Plot of $g(x)$ against $f(x)$, illustrating an example of the desired behaviour of a "density" function.]

Of course, this works only because $f$ is symmetric in this specific case, otherwise the curve would not look like a well-defined function (there could be several values of $g(x)$ at each corresponding $f(x)$). But you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

I might try defining the density in a limiting fashion.  We could set

$$
g_\epsilon(t) = \mu\Bigl(\{x : |f(x) - t| < \varepsilon\}\Bigr),
$$

where $g_\epsilon$ is supported on the image of $f$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, and

$$
G_\epsilon(t) = \frac{g_\epsilon(t)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_\epsilon(s)\,ds},
$$

and hope that

$$
G(t) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} G_\epsilon(t)
$$

exists in some sense.

---

For a concrete example let's consider $f(x) = x^2$ defined on the interval $0 < x < 1$.  Here we have

$$
|x^2 - t| < \epsilon \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \sqrt{\max\{0,t-\epsilon\}} < x < \sqrt{\min\{t+\epsilon,1\}},
$$

so

$$
g_\epsilon(t) = \sqrt{\min\{t+\epsilon,1\}} - \sqrt{\max\{0,t-\epsilon\}}.
$$

The integral of $g_\epsilon(t)$ can be calculated explicitly, and it can be shown that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_\epsilon(s)\,ds = 2\epsilon + O(\epsilon^{3/2})
$$

for small $\epsilon > 0$.  Consequently, for fixed $0 < t < 1$ we have

$$
G(t) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} G_\epsilon(t) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{t+\epsilon} - \sqrt{t-\epsilon}}{2\epsilon} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}.
$$

Intuitively this result seems to align with the desired properties of the density: when $f(x)$ spends a lot of time near $t$, $G(t)$ is large, and when $f(x)$ spends less time near $t$, $G(t)$ is small.

Comment: The example I give is invertible.  When $f$ is not invertible it would probably not be simple to retrieve a closed form expression for $G$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this looks like a nice definition, but I fear there is no way this will lead to an analytic expression if $f$ can't be inverted, mainly because I don't see how you would then isolate $x$ like you did in your first inequality. Shouldn't the integral be calculated on the image of $f$, instead of the whole real line? (That would be $(0,1)$ in your example)

Comment: Right, that's definitely a drawback of this formulation - there must be a better one. At least with this one you can still retrieve analytic information about the distribution near points of interest. For example, if your function has a unique critical point $x_0$ of order $n$ with height $f(x_0) = t_0$ then I think it should be possible to show something like $$G(t) = C|t-t_0|^{(1-n)/n} + \hat G(t_0) + o(1)$$ as $t \to t_0$ for some constant $C$. (...)

Comment: (...) Here $\hat G$ is the distribution of the function $\hat f$, where $\hat f = f$ outside of an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $x_0$.  And you're right, I required that $g_\epsilon$ only be supported on the image of $f$, so the integral over the real line equals the integral over just the image.

Comment: One last remark.  If $f'(x) \neq 0$ and $f(x) = t$ then by the inverse function theorem we have $(f^{-1})'(t) = 1/f'(f^{-1}(t))$.  This can be used to calculate the distributions of monotonic functions numerically up to a constant factor.  For your example $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ we could take advantage of the symmetry using the Mathematica code `finv = Interpolation[Table[{E^(-x^2), x}, {x, -5, 0, 1/1000}]];
ListPlot[Table[{x, -(E^finv[x]^2/(2 finv[x]))}, {x, 1/10000, 1, 1/1000}], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]` to get the plot http://i.stack.imgur.com/j11ve.png

Comment: Of course using that formula the distribution of $e^{-x^2}$ can be explicitly calculated as $$G(t) = \frac{C}{t\sqrt{-\log t}},$$ where $C$ depends on the interval you're interested in.